# first-child selector is not working with dd

Tags: css, css-selectors

The first-child selector on dd is not working, why?

```
<dl>
    <dt>definition term</dt>
    <dd>description</dd>
    <dd>description</dd>
    <dd>description</dd>
</dl>

dd:first-child{
    /*styling here not work*/
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N4Jqg/1/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) pseudo-class instead.

```css
dd:first-of-type {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/N4Jqg/7/)**.

That's because `<dd>` is not the *first child* of its parent.

[`element:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) represents the *first child* of its parent, matching the `element`. And in this particular instance, the first child of `<dl>` element is a `<dt>` element; Not a `<dl>`.

From the **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)**:

> The `:first-of-type` CSS pseudo-class represents the *first sibling* of
>   its *type* in the list of children of its parent element.

Which the term of *type* refers to the HTML element type. Hence `dd:first-of-type` selects the first `<dd>` element in the children tree of its parent.

Alternatively, In this particular case you could select the first `<dd>` element by using [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) as: `dt + dd`. **[(Demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/N4Jqg/8/)**.

Answer (score 3):

For cross browser compatibility (<=IE8), you could even use:

```
dt + dd {
  display:none;
}
```

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/seemly/N4Jqg/5/

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
dd:first-of-type{
    display: none;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/N4Jqg/2/)